# VSTS Extension with Angular2

Tags: javascript, angular, azure-devops-rest-api

I'm currently trying to create Visual Studio Team Services Extension, using Angular2 including its CLI: https://github.com/DrMueller/Ng-Vsts

Unfortunately, I can't get this to run: While I can hook on the VSTS and see the tab-entry as well as the "loading...", it seems like VSTS blocks the loading of the javascript-bundles, since I always get:

> Refused to execute script from
>   'https://drmueller.gallery.vsassets.io/inline.bundle.js' because its
>   MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type
>   checking is enabled.

What bothers me is that fact, that I find absolutely no information on the web to make these two systems going together, so is it probably not even possible in the first place?
Is it probably more likey to get this working without the Angular-CLI, but for example using Gulp-Tasks?

Comment: Could you run the app if remove VSS.SDK.js reference and related code? Based on my test, it throws exception Unable to get property 'apply' of undefined or null reference error.

Comment: BTW, that extension is not work for me.

Comment: Hm VSS.SDK.js is needed I think, since it will be the entry point to the whole VSS-API. I think the main problem is the fact, that VSTS kindahow forbids to load Javascript in a Body?

Comment: The unable to get property 'apply'... issue is related to IE, it works fine Microsoft Edge. Regarding that extension, I can reproduce that issue (MIME type is text/html) I am trying to deal with this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that the JavaScript files can’t be in the body, need to be included in head.

For that sample, the related JS files will be included in the body (behind `<app-root>`) and you can’t include them in the head (because it will throw app-root did not match error).

Load the JS after app being loaded:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
});
```

Comment: Hm Thanks, I thought about adding another JavaScript file in the Head, which listens to the Docoment-ready event and then calls the Angular Files, would that be a workaround?

Comment: @MatthiasMüller How do you call angular files in document ready event. I tested with $.getScript('url') and $('<script />', { type: 'text/javascript', src: "inline.bundle.js" }).appendTo('head');, not work, the type is application/json instead of application/javascript. Note: the angular app works fine in local with these ways.

Comment: I didn't test it out so far, just looking for possible workarounds. Is there a possibility to request a change in order to make this kindahow working? It's a bit unfortunate we can't just such a rich Framework like Angular just because of a minor detail.

Comment: @MatthiasMüller I also tried it with systemjs, but can't upload the package to vsts. Could not find another way. Do you know other ways?

Comment: Sorry but I already have Angular 5 dashboards in VSTS build with angular CLI (I have to eject just to be able to add 
"externals": [
    /^VSS\/.*/, /^TFS\/.*/, /^ReleaseManagement\/.*/, /^q$/
  ], line but I can guarentee you it just works.

Answer (score 1):

I asked back on the Angular-CLI GitHub, and I can quite easily start the JavaScript only after the DOM is loaded. Here the discussion: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/6205

All i have to do is to replace the main.ts bootstraping with this lines:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
});
```

But since the Angular-CLI adds the JavaScripts anyway, I've also created a small program, which removes them from the body: https://github.com/DrMueller/HtmlJavaScriptInjector

Tackling everything together, I can now build, remove the HTML and publish the extension with this PowerShell:

```
$basePath = 'C:\MyGit\Personal\ng-vsts';
$distPath = $basePath + '\dist';

Set-Location $basePath;

### Build
ng build;


### Replace HTML with Js -- Start
$relativeSubpath = '\script\internals\html-replacer';
$htmlReplacerPath = $basePath + $relativeSubpath;
Set-Location $htmlReplacerPath;

dotnet '.\Mmu.Hji.Console.dll' $distPath;
### Replace HTML with Js -- End


### Publish extension -- Start
Set-Location $basePath;
$publishKey = Get-Content 'C:\Users\matthias.mueller\Dropbox\AssetsAndTools\VSTS_Key.txt';
tfx extension publish --manifest-globs vss-extension.json --rev-version -t $publishKey;
### Publish extension -- End
```

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, to make you SPA work in the Azure DevOps, you need to modify your `index.html`.

First, you need to remove all scripts after `<app-root>`. For that, you can use this powershell script:

```
$folder_prefix = "dist\angular"
$folderPath = Join-Path -Path $PSScriptRoot -ChildPath $folder_prefix
$indexHTML = Join-Path -Path $folderPath -ChildPath "index.html"

$scripts = @()
$pattern = "<script\b[^>]*>(.*?)<\/script>"
Select-String -Path $indexHTML -Pattern $pattern -AllMatches | %{$_.Matches} | ForEach-Object {
    $script = Select-String -InputObject $_ -Pattern '"(.*)"' -AllMatches | %{$_.Matches} | ForEach-Object {
        $scriptPath = Join-Path -Path $folderPath -ChildPath $_.ToString().Replace('"', '')
        Write-Host ("Found " + $scriptPath)
        $scripts += $scriptPath
    }
}

$scriptContentHolder = ""
$scripts | ForEach-Object {
    Write-Host ("Reading " + $_)   
    $scriptContentHolder += Get-Content $_ -Raw -Encoding UTF8
}

Write-Host "Replacing index.html"
$html = Get-Content $indexHTML -Raw -Encoding UTF8
$html -replace $pattern, ("<script>`n" + $scriptContentHolder + "`n</script>`n") | Out-File $indexHTML -Encoding utf8
Write-Host "Replaced"
```

You can save this powershell code to the root folder. The main purpose of this script is to read `dist\angular\index.html`, find all scripts, read them and replace inline.

And in your `package.json` just add new script:

```
"scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "extension:create": "ng build && powershell -file devops-optimizer.ps1 && tfx extension create --output-path dist/azure-devops",
    "powershell:index": "powershell -file devops-optimizer.ps1"
  }
```